# Eclipse Warning with Java HashMap

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, hashmap

Eclipse is saying "HashMap is a raw type" When I use the following code

```
HashMap = new HashMap();
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Try something like: HashMap<String, String> h = new HashMap<String, String>();  As others mentioned, you aren't specifying the type for the key and value.  It is safer to give this info, for type-checking.

Comment: @James Or better `final Map<String,String> h = new HashMap<String,String>();`.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - True, using Map would be better, but I was just following his example. :)

Answer (score 17):

Eclipse will give you that warning when you use a non-[Generic](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html) `HashMap` using Java 5 or newer.

See Also: The [Generics Lesson](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) in Sun's Java Tutorials.

Edit:  Actually, here, I'll give an example too:

Say I want to map someone's name to their `Person` object:

```
Map<String, Person> map = new HashMap<String, Person>();
// The map.get method now returns a Person
// The map.put method now requires a String and a Person
```

These are checked at compile-time; the type information is lost at run-time due to how Java implements Generics.

Comment: map.get() still takes an Object. It might seem surprising (check the javadoc if you don't believe me), but Josh Bloch commented on this once, saying that if they had changed the signature to get(K key) they might cause errors for code that is, in fact, correct.

Comment: @waxwing:  Interesting.  I should have noticed that when I looked at the Map/HashMap pages.  I'll fix that.  Oh, I also forgot to mention get now returns a `Person` object.  Whoops.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: technically, `get` still returns `Object`, but the generics tell the compiler to add a cast to `Person`.

Comment: @Brian: That's done internally, though.  It's documented in the `Map`/`HashMap` docs as returning type `V`, unlike its argument which takes an `Object`.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing *wrong* exactly, but you are missing out on the wonderful world of generics.  Depending on what constraints you want to place on the types used in your map, you should add type parameters.  For example:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Answer (score 1):

That is missing generics, i.e. .  If you don't know thise then set the eclipse compiler to java 1.4

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

instead (obviously replacing the key type (String) and value type (Integer)).

Answer (score 0):

That usually means you're mixing generic code with non-generic code.

But as your example wont even compile its rather hard to tell....

Answer (score 0):

It's missing the generic type. You should specify the key-value generic pair for your map. For instance, the following is a declaration that instantiates a `HashMap` with String type key and Integer type value.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

All of these are valid answers, you could also use the @SurpressWarnings annotation to get the same result, without having to resort to actual generics. ;)

Answer (score 0):

hashmap is a raw type and hence should be parameterised ie
what ever the data we get through the haspmap function their type must be declared for getting its functions

for example

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

With the latest Java, you do not have to explicitly mention the variable types in declaration. You can simply put:

```
 = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: For posterity, refer to the exact version of Java where this answer takes effect. This answer can be further improved by adding links to relevant official documentation.